# Compiling proto files in Django during runserver

Tags: django, protocol-buffers

I am using Django, and I have `protoc` installed on the machine. I would like to automatically compile all of the proto files found in all app directories when I start a server:

```
./manage.py runserver ...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar at all with `protoc`, but you can do whatever with `runserver`. You need to create a custom `runserver` [django admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/) to override the default. Here is a sample:

```
import os
import subprocess
import atexit
import signal

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver import Command\
    as StaticfilesRunserverCommand


class Command(StaticfilesRunserverCommand):

    def inner_run(self, *args, **options):
        self.start_something()
        return super(Command, self).inner_run(*args, **options)

    def start_something(self):
        self.stdout.write('>>> Starting something')
        self.some_process = subprocess.Popen(
            '.....',
            shell=True,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=self.stdout,
            stderr=self.stderr,
        )

        self.stdout.write('>>> Some process on pid {0}'.format(self.some_process.pid))

        def kill_some_process(pid):
            self.stdout.write('>>> Closing some process')
            os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)

        atexit.register(kill_some_process, self.some_process.pid)
```

Please notice that you need to derive this from `django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver` and not from `django.core.management.base` or you lose `collectstatic` and stuff.

Also, you obviously do not need to kill the process if it exits by itself anyway.